# When trying to create Application Menus using Model Fragments (XMI Model) in Eclipse e4. The created menu is getting disabled by default

Tags: eclipse, e4, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I'm actually migrating my Workspace from 3.x to Eclipse e4 version. I created one new menu using Model Fragments as described in the "Section 7.6. Creating a model contribution" under the following [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#e4commandsin3x) .

With these steps, the menu item was getting created succesfully but it remains disabled :( even though the enabled [] check-box is checked by default.

What could be the reason behind this  ??

The Fragment.e4xmi code which I've used is :

```
 <fragment:ModelFragments xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:commands="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/commands" xmlns:fragment="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/fragment" xmlns:menu="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/menu" xmi:id="_c8CZsFVoEeWXIM1iTwboYg">
 <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_ylQWEFYyEeWz-PkqHRIpVg" featurename="commands" parentElementId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
<elements xsi:type="commands:Command" xmi:id="_CqXYcFYzEeWz-PkqHRIpVg" elementId="test_emf_project.command.sample" commandName="Sample"/>
  </fragments>
 <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_HPsk0FYzEeWz-PkqHRIpVg" featurename="Handlers" parentElementId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
<elements xsi:type="commands:Handler" xmi:id="_KcOLMFYzEeWz-PkqHRIpVg" elementId="test_emf_project.handler.0" contributionURI="bundleclass://Test_EMF_Project/com.ami.launch.HandlerImplementation" command="_CqXYcFYzEeWz-PkqHRIpVg"/>
  </fragments>
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_Q9KvsFYzEeWz-PkqHRIpVg" featurename="menuContributions" parentElementId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
  <elements xsi:type="menu:MenuContribution" xmi:id="_VRqDsFYzEeWz-PkqHRIpVg" elementId="test_emf_project.menucontribution.0" parentId="org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
    <children xsi:type="menu:Menu" xmi:id="_gzz4QFYzEeWz-PkqHRIpVg" elementId="test_emf_project.menu.custommenu" label="Custommenu">
     <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_vHCtUFYzEeWz-PkqHRIpVg" elementId="test_emf_project.handledmenuitem.openDialog" label="Open Dialog" iconURI="" command="_CqXYcFYzEeWz-PkqHRIpVg"/>
   </children>
  </elements>
 </fragments>
</fragment:ModelFragments>
```

Comment: Is this a Direct Menu Item? Have you define a class in the 'Class URI'?

Comment: @greg-449: No, This is not a Direct Menu Item, It is a 'Handled Menu Item'. Yes, I'd defined a Handler class and mapped it to the Handler Model Fragment ('Class URI' field of Handler Model Fragment).

Comment: You will have to show us more details because there should not be any problem with this.

Comment: @greg-449 :  I'd uploaded the .e4xmi file for your reference [here](https://www.4shared.com/account/home.jsp#dir=XmQnTOEc). Please find the attached file. Please correct me if I missed out anything.

Comment: Additional Information : I'm trying to launch the product as an Eclipse Product (org.eclipse.sdk.ide).

Comment: @greg-449:   If I use 'Direct Menu Item', then there are no issues as the Menu is directly been associated with the 'Class URI'. 
But I need to use 'Handled Menu Item' which uses the Command Handler approach.

Comment: Sorry but I am not downloading things from a service that requires signup. Handled Menu Items work fine, check the Command and Handler definitions.

Comment: @greg-449 :   I've pasted the Fragment.e4xmi code here (in the Issue Synopsis section). I think  now it will be easy for you, instead of downloading the file from 4shared link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'Feature Name' for the handlers fragment is set to `Handlers` - it should be all lower case `handlers`.

Comment: Thanks !! It works for me, But what is the relationship does Fragments has with cases ?. It is just a name right ? why does it gets disabled if the case aren't lowercase ?

Comment: Feature Name is not just a name, it must match an attribute of the element that you are extending.  It tells Eclipse which part of the element you are extending.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I spent a full day on this digging my head without knowing that case is the problem for a simple menu creation :( :( 

Thanks You Greg for your help and thanks for Stack Overflow !! :) :).

Comment: Hi Greg, 
          As suggested by you, the menu item was enabled after converting it  into lowercase. But when I export the product I'm getting the error as in my next comment.

Comment: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt [28]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core; bundle-version="0.9.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core; bundle-version="0.10.100.v20140424-2042"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core [27]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.batik.css; bundle-version="1.7.0"
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:158

Comment: I exported the product as an Eclipse product. I have just one plugin which contains the .product file and this Fragemtn.e4xmi file . When tried to export the product and trying to launch the exe I'm running into problems.

Comment: This is a new question so ask another question